# OpenGL ES 2.0 several scenes

Tags: c++, iphone, ios, opengl-es-2.0

How to implement transition between several scenes that use opengl?

I have 2 different scenes. each create its frame and render buffers and bind it. But then I try to switch between these scenes - nothing happens... I tried to delete all buffers when swithing but it's doesn't work. The First scene is still visible..

Answer (score 0):

Well, in my experience you may need to dispose of the textures for the first scene's visuals.
A quick idea is using psm studio's approach to OpenGLES.

```
public TitleScene ()
{
  this.Camera.SetViewFromViewport();
  _texture = new Texture2D("Application/images/title.png",false);
  _ti = new TextureInfo(_texture);
  SpriteUV titleScreen = new SpriteUV(_ti);
  titleScreen.Scale = _ti.TextureSizef;
  titleScreen.Pivot = new Vector2(0.5f,0.5f);
  titleScreen.Position = new Vector2(Director.Instance.GL.Context.GetViewport().Width/2,
      Director.Instance.GL.Context.GetViewport().Height/2);
  this.AddChild(titleScreen);
  public override void Update (float dt)
  {
    base.Update (dt);
    var touches = Touch.GetData(0).ToArray();
    if((touches.Length >0 && touches[0].Status == TouchStatus.Down) || Input2.GamePad0.Cross.Press)
    {
      Director.Instance.ReplaceScene(new MenuScene());
    }
  }

  ~TitleScene()
  {
    _texture.Dispose();
    _ti.Dispose ();
  }
}
```

I hope this will give you some help on what you are missing.